# correlation with 3D matrices from MatLab using R software

Tags: r, matlab, matrix, correlation

I have two 3D (12x12x10) matrices obtained from Functional Connectivity Analysis in CONN Software and in .mat format. Each 3D matrix is composed by 10 individual matrices of 12 regions of interest. One is considering a rest condition and the other a task condition. I want to compare the differences in FC performing the correlation between the two 3D matrices in R, but the I dont how to make R understand that I have a 3D matrix! It mix in a odd 2D matrix. Using the following code:

```
# Load connectivity matrix
mat<-read.table("R/Matriz/neural", header = FALSE)
View(mat)
r<-corr.test(mat,mat)
```

And trying to compute a correlation matrix with only 1 values, I got a completely different matrix:

```
Call:corr.test(x = mat, y = mat)
Correlation matrix 
       V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
V1   1.00  0.84  0.43 -0.14  0.02 -0.30 -0.20 -0.08 -0.04 -0.20 -0.46 -0.51
V2   0.84  1.00  0.55 -0.03  0.02 -0.23 -0.12 -0.02 -0.04 -0.13 -0.49 -0.50
V3   0.43  0.55  1.00  0.15  0.20 -0.03  0.14  0.35  0.09 -0.08 -0.31 -0.23
V4  -0.14 -0.03  0.15  1.00  0.54  0.45  0.57  0.51  0.23 -0.09  0.20  0.19
V5   0.02  0.02  0.20  0.54  1.00 -0.18  0.04  0.16  0.80  0.12  0.37  0.39
V6  -0.30 -0.23 -0.03  0.45 -0.18  1.00  0.68  0.51 -0.44 -0.31 -0.20 -0.25
V7  -0.20 -0.12  0.14  0.57  0.04  0.68  1.00  0.69 -0.20 -0.11  0.01  0.02
V8  -0.08 -0.02  0.35  0.51  0.16  0.51  0.69  1.00 -0.04 -0.11 -0.13  0.02
V9  -0.04 -0.04  0.09  0.23  0.80 -0.44 -0.20 -0.04  1.00  0.40  0.55  0.60
V10 -0.20 -0.13 -0.08 -0.09  0.12 -0.31 -0.11 -0.11  0.40  1.00  0.45  0.51
V11 -0.46 -0.49 -0.31  0.20  0.37 -0.20  0.01 -0.13  0.55  0.45  1.00  0.87
V12 -0.51 -0.50 -0.23  0.19  0.39 -0.25  0.02  0.02  0.60  0.51  0.87  1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the correlation between two different matrices (unlike in your code), and treat all the values as independent data. The way you describe your data may hint that perhaps the correlation between these 2 is not the best way to compare, but if you want to compare, one way is unrolling your matrices, as the fact that they are 3D is not relevant to compute the correlation between them. If you make them 3D, then R assumes variables and structure.

try

```
r<-corr.test(as.vector(mat),as.vector(mat2))
```

Comment: I had the same result.